# type command (Powershell) throws 'A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument' error

Tags: powershell, uglifyjs

I'm trying to use 'uglifyjs' in order to minify all of my javascript files into one '.js' file in order to get the karma ng-scenario e2e testing to function properly. However when I input this

```
type My.js MyLogon.js MyMenu.js Common\directives\BaseDirectives.js Common\factories\BaseFactories.js Module\AccountConfirmationModule.js Module\AccountModule.js Module\ApplicationModule.js Module\ApplicationRoleModule.js Module\HeaderModule.js Module\Index.js Module\LogOnModule.js Module\PasswordModule.js Module\QAModule.js Module\UsernameModule.js > files.min.js | uglifyjs -o files.min.js
```

I get the following error

> Get-Content : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts
>   argument 'MyLogon.js'. At line:1 char:5

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you format the code section to a more readable form? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `type` command in Cmd shell supports typing multiple files at the same time. File names are just space separated. In Powershell, `type` is an alias for `Get-Content`. It supports multiple source files, but doesn't use space separation. An array is needed, as specified by the `-Path` parameter that supports a String array:

```
man type    
Get-Content [-Path] <string[]> [-Credential <PSCredential>] ...
```

Try passing the cmdlet an array of file names. Like so,

```
type @("My.js", "MyLogon.js", "MyMenu.js")  | uglifyjs -o files.min.js
```

Comment: FYI the @() and quotes aren't necessary e.g. `Get-Content my.js,MyLogon.js,MyMenu.js | ...` works fine.

Answer (score 1):

In powershell, a list is separated by comma, not space

```
type file1, file2, file3
```

Answer (score 0):

If all the files are in the curent folder and there are no other *.js files:

```
if (test-path files.min.js) { remove-item files.min.js }
gci *.js | foreach{ type $_ >> files.min.js }
uglifyjs -o files.min.js
```

If this is not the case, the list can be set up this way:

```
$files = ("My.js", "MyLogon.js", "MyMenu.js", "Common\directives\BaseDirectives.js", "Common\factories\BaseFactories.js", "Module\AccountConfirmationModule.js", "Module\AccountModule.js", "Module\ApplicationModule.js", "Module\ApplicationRoleModule.js", "Module\HeaderModule.js", "Module\Index.js", "Module\LogOnModule.js", "Module\PasswordModule.js", "Module\QAModule.js", "Module\UsernameModule.js")
if (test-path files.min.js) { remove-item files.min.js }
$files | foreach{ type $_ >> files.min.js }
uglifyjs -o files.min.js
```